# Javascript: How to call this.Something() from this.img.onload = SomeLoadFunction;

Tags: javascript

Ok I have some code similar to this...

```
Thing function () {    
  var img = new Image;    
  DoSomeStuff function() {    
  //Some stuff here that can't be done until my img is loaded...    
};

InitMe function(src) {    
  this.img.onLoad = this.DoSomeStuff;     
  this.img.src = src;    
};    
}

var Test = new Thing();    
Test.InitMe("some string");
```

Which obviously doesn't work because `this.DoSomeStuff` stops being `Thing.DoSomeStuff` and becomes `img.DoSomeStuff`

So I guess what I need to know is, how can I call the `Thing.DoSomeStuff()` function from the `img.onLoad`....

Answer (score 1):

On ES5 you can use:

```
this.img.onLoad = this.DoSomeStuff.bind(this);
```

or:

```
var self = this;
this.img.onLoad = function() {
    self.DoSomeStuff();
}
```

p.s. your current code isn't remotely legal.  Among other things, the variables have the wrong scope (or aren't properties of `this`) and your function declaration syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You may want this

```
function Thing() {    
    this.img = new Image;    
    this.DoSomeStuff=function(){
        // do something
    };

    var self=this;
    this.InitMe=function(src) {   
        self.img.src = src;
        self.img.onload = function(){
            self.DoSomeStuff();
        }
    };    
}

var Test = new Thing();    
Test.InitMe("example.png");​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tDgFm/3/).

Comment: @Alnitak, what is not working ? why should I log `this` instead of `self` because `self` refers to the object now ?

Comment: It doesn't work because you've done nothing to change `this` in the `DoSomeStuff` function.  It leaves the OP with exactly the problem he had before.  He _could_ use `self` inside that function, but the point of the question is how to fix `this` correctly so that he doesn't have to change that function.

Comment: Is that necessary in this case ? what's the downside here in this particular example and what do you suggest instead ?

Comment: The downside is the need to use the wrong variable to refer to `this`.  My suggestions are in my answer.